# I was trying to see the seasonal and trend factor in the timeseries, but graph is not working correctly. Tried after deleting cache memory too

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, timeserieschart, decomposition

Hi was trying to do seasonal_decomposition for a time series, but wasn't getting proper result:

[image]

```
date        value
2020-02-01  67.05
2020-03-01  69.08
2020-06-01  70.25
2020-07-01  68.74
2020-08-01  67.31
.
.
.
till 2022-11-04
```

Code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
df_add_decompose = seasonal_decompose(df_modified, model = 'additive', period=12)
df_add_decompose.plot()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to sort index:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
df_modified = df_modified.sort_index()
df_add_decompose = seasonal_decompose(df_modified, model = 'additive', period=12)
df_add_decompose.plot()
```